Simplicial right Kan extensions and Cartesian transformations
I will write the concrete question first, in case the answer is clear independently of the context:

Question: Given an $\infty$-topos $\mathfrak{X}$ and a diagram $F\colon\Delta^1\times\Delta_+^{op}\to\mathfrak{X}$, is it true that $F$ is a right Kan extension of its restriction to $ (0,[-1])\cup(\{1\}\times\Delta_+^{op})$ if and only if $F$ defines a Cartesian natural transformation from $F_0=F\vert_{\{0\}\times\Delta_+^{op}}$ to $F_1=F\vert_{\{1\}\times\Delta_+^{op}}$?

This question is coming from Remark 5.2.6.28 in Lurie's Higher Algebra. I am using it in a paper so have been trying to work through the details, but am stuck on one point.  Specifically, the equivalence of what he calls condition (i) and the pair of conditions (i₁) and (i₂). I'll write out the details here.
Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the (nerve of the) category $\Delta^1\times\Delta_+^{op}$ and let $\mathcal{J}\subset\mathcal{K}$ be the full subcategory spanned by the objects $(0,[-1])$, $(1,[-1])$ and $(1,[0])$. This looks like the below image, with $\mathcal{J}$ in red (apologies, I can't scale it to a more reasonable size without making it tiny).

Condition (i) of the proposition is that a functor $F\colon\mathcal{K}\to\mathfrak{X}$, where $\mathfrak{X}$ is an $\infty$-topos, is a right Kan extension of its restriction along $\mathcal{J}\subset\mathcal{K}$. Lurie claims that this condition is equivalent to the following two conditions:
(i₀) The restriction of $F$ to $\{1\}\times\Delta_+^{op}$ is a right Kan extension of its restriction to (the full subcategory containing) $\{1\}\times(\Delta_+^{\leq 0})^{op}$.
(i₁) The functor $F$ determines a Cartesian natural transformation from $F_0=F\vert_{\{0\}\times\Delta_+^{op}}$ to $F_1=F\vert_{\{1\}\times\Delta_+^{op}}$.
Recall that being a Cartesian natural transformation means that every naturality square in $F$, thought of as a functor $\Delta^1\to\mathfrak{X}^{\Delta_+^{op}}$, is a pullback square in $\mathfrak{X}$.
Lurie cites Proposition 4.3.2.8 of Higher Topos Theory as justification for this. I believe that I can use this proposition to show that Condition (i) is equivalent to the following two conditions:
(j₀) The restriction of $F$ to (the full subcategory containing) $(0,[-1])\cup(\{1\}\times\Delta_+^{op})$ is a right Kan extension of its restriction to (the full subcategory containing) $(0,[-1])\cup(\{1\}\times(\Delta_+^{\leq 0})^{op})$.
(j₁)$F$ is a right Kan extension of its restriction to $(0,[-1])\cup(\{1\}\times\Delta_+^{op})$.
I don't think the inclusion of $(0,[-1])$ is essential here, it's just the thing that made the most sense to me. However, I would like to conclude that (j₁) is equivalent to $F$ defining a Cartesian natural transformation, but I don't immediately see how. I suspect one can show that it being a right Kan extension implies the Cartesian condition by taking the right Kan extension diagram and precomposing it with comma squares built from the inclusion of cospan diagrams into $(0,[-1])\cup(\Delta^1\times\Delta_+^{op})$ (since the right Kan extension of a cospan is a pullback). But I am not sure how to show the converse (in other words, can I build the right Kan extension purely from the pullback squares?).
